# Embedding youtube video in markdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, rubygems, markdown, embedding

i use the ruby gem **formatize** to parse my markdown-formated text. now i want to embed a youtube-video into the markdown text, but whenever i add the iframe snippet, the gem (or markdown?) just removes it from the output. any advise?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to get formatize to ignore `<iframe>` tags.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265534/how-can-i-embed-a-youtube-video-in-a-markdown-enabled-text-field).

You can have markdown + HTML together so it sounds like it's an issue with the gem.  Notice how the markdown syntax recommends that the older YouTube markup is embedded via [direct HTML](http://help.couch.it/Markdown_Syntax).  You might be able to get away using the older `<object>` tag approach; I think it's still supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to formatize's documentation, you should pass :safe => true into the markdown function (this opens a security hole, so be sure to run your own, customized sanitization)

That doesn't work so I am instead using my own copy of formatizes function that does no sanitization (yet):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def post_body(post)
    (post.body.blank? ? "" : BlueCloth.new(post.body).to_html).html_safe
  end
end
```