# Has anyone figured out how to embed video using the Redcarpet gem for Markdown in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, redcarpet

Wondering if anyone has a good solution for this. My app is displaying nothing when embedding both the old and new version of YouTube's video embed code. I'm using GitHub's Markdown Gem [Redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet), and it doesn't appear that there is any information in their 'issues' section that would help solve this problem. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755063/embedding-youtube-video-in-markdown) on Stack Overflow but it deals with a different issue.

Has anyone figured out how to embed video using the Redcarpet gem for Markdown in Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure the :filter_html flag is disabled in your renderer.

```
Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(:filter_html => false)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to let only certain html tags through, you have to create a custom Renderer ([here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381230/how-to-extend-redcarpet-to-support-auto-linking-user-mentions/16473771#16473771)) and define the `block_html` method.

For example:

```
class MyRenderer < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_html(raw_html)
    if raw_html =~ /^<iframe.*>$/ # You may want to optimize this.
      raw_html
    end
  end
end
```

Then set :filter_html back to true when you call your own renderer:

```
MyRenderer.new(:filter_html => true)
```

Comment: Yes. :filter_html strips native html from the output, relying on markdown syntax instead.

Comment: Do you know of anyway to do it w/o allowing all html? Is there a way just to allow certain tags? Sanatize and markdown?