# How to extend redcarpet to support auto linking user mentions?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, redcarpet

On my rails3 application I want to use redcarpet to handle user's posts and the user comment section.  As such I'd like to extend redcarpet to support turning @username into a link to a user on my site.  I know redcarpet is written in C but is there anyway easy way to extend it in ruby?  How hard would it be to write it in C?  Should I just do this outside of redcarpet?

Also I'm intrested in some other extensions of redcarpet that would be shorthand for linking to other models in my app.  I'm not sure the syntax yet but I'm guessing it would be similar to how github handles linking to issues.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found it pretty easy to extend redcarpet's parser in Ruby for my rails 3 app. It wasn't scary at all.

First, start by deriving a class from Redcarpet's HTML renderer and override the preprocess method as recommended in the docs. In Rails 3.2 and Rails 4, this file can go anywhere and you don't need to require it. I use a 'services' folder to hold code like this.

```
# app/services/my_flavored_markdown.rb
class MyFlavoredMarkdown < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def preprocess(text)
    text
  end
end
```

Next step is to add methods that do text substitutions you want. Here I use regex to wrap text that looks like "@mention" in an HTML span tag with a css class 'mention'.

```
# app/services/my_flavored_markdown.rb
class MyFlavoredMarkdown < Redcarpet::Render::HTML

  def preprocess(text)
    wrap_mentions(text)
  end

  def wrap_mentions(text)
    text.gsub! /(^|\s)(@\w+)/ do
      "#{$1}<span class='mention'>#{$2}</span>"
    end
    text
  end

end
```

You could just as easily look up a user's profile page and wrap the @mention in an anchor tag instead. In my case, I also made methods for emoticons and hashtags that worked the same way and chained the methods together.

The last step is to add a helper that accepts some text, creates an instance of your Redcarpet-derived class, passes the text into that for processing, and returns the html result.

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def flavored_markdown_to_html(text)
  renderer = MyFlavoredMarkdown.new()
  # These options might be helpful but are not required
  options = {
    safe_links_only: true,
    no_intra_emphasis: true,
    autolink: true
  }
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, options).render(text)
}
```

In your views you can call it like this:

`<%= flavored_markdown_to_html("This is something worth @mentioning") %>`

The output would then be:

`This is something worth <span class='mention'>@mentioning</span>`.

Comment: Also, if the rendered results won't be cached, you probably don't want to be doing database lookups during every render. An alternative is to use the example I have here, then use javascript to intercept clicks on span.mention elements, look up the mention url and redirect the user.

Comment: To those who don't want the @-sign in the link's href: `/(^|\s)@(\w+)/` and `"#{$1}<span class='mention'>@#{$2}</span>"`

Answer (score 1):

I once tried to extend `redcarpet`, but found it very difficult. If there are no other dependencies on `redcarpet` I'd recommend you try `rpeg-markdown` which is a (somewhat outdated) Ruby gem providing bindings to the excellent [peg-markdown](http://github.com/jgm/peg-markdown).

`peg-markdown` is a markdown interpreter written as a formal grammar. This means that it is very easy to extend it with own syntax. I've successfully extended `peg-markdown` for my own projects (see [my fork here](http://github.com/rekado/peg-markdown)) and I found it to be *much* simpler than fiddling with `redcarpet`'s custom parser code.

I also found `peg-markdown` to have fewer bugs.

The Ruby bindings may have to be made current by updating the git submodule. (I'm planning to submit a pull request to update `rpeg-markdown` to the latest version of `peg-markdown`.)